# SSL access to a js recently deployed APP on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

My Heroku node.js deployed APP on Sept7 suddently (as of from Sept 14th 00:00hrs on) doesn't work and instead I get a

SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

error message.

What has changed?
How can it be fixed?
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are really using the port 443 (https) instead of port 80 (http).